# Not sure of the problem with our new Dwarf Orange Tree

Tags: fruit-trees

As the title states, not sure if there is a problem OR if one is going to start.
We've had this new dwarf orange tree for 2 weeks.  Today I noticed on a few of the leaves underneath that there are white spots.  It does not scrape off.  Is this mildew and if so, what do I do about it?  I want to catch it early, as stated before this is a new tree with only a few leaves showing this problem.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.   Thank You !

Comment: I think a picture showing the situation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Deb, there are many possibilities. Take a photo during good daylight hours, making sure that it is clear and in focus. By all means post the photo here but your local garden centre staff will have a more informed answer. They know the problems in your area, right? If they don’t know, ask to speak to someone more experienced or find a better garden centre. 
Cheerio

Answer (score 0):

With out pictures it is hard to tell for sure, could be scale, a sap sucking insect, lots of different types of scale, one is fuzzy.